# How to add option value = "" in select boxed in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, form-helpers

I want to use jQuery validation plugin for select boxes, but I don't know how to add  value ="" in select. Here is my code:

```
   <%= f.select :language, options_for_select([
       "--- please select ---",
        "Arabic",
        "Chinese"
         ])
        %>
```

I want to add

```
    value="" option="please select"
```

How I can do it in Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :language, options_for_select([
    "Arabic",
    "Chinese"
     ], {:prompt => "please select"})
    %>
```

Comment: Stays the same `<option value="--- please select ---">--- please select ---</option>`

Comment: Apologies, neglected to remove your please select line... now edited.

Comment: Tried this too. Strange, in documentation it tells that should work. Could be problem,that I'm using SelectBox plugin ?

Comment: There is a problem with the code in your edit - you added a second %> which was not required. I have edited to remove the capitals, which I think was what you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes, though I think you might want to ask another question with some specifics about the validation - there is no indication in this question what the problem is with your validation. I would ask another question since this one has been answered.

Comment: I have over 50 questions this months, so I can't do this at this moment) My validation for select box is not working when I'm adding `required: true`.

Comment: Or you can look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721471/cant-get-why-url-custom-validation-method-for-jquery-validation-plugin-not-work/12721581#12721581 - I can't make my default url validation working.